# Reactjs form data is not inserting into mysql database

Tags: php, reactjs

I create a project in reactjs and php.
The reactjs part working but php code is not.
It's not inserting a data to mysql database.
And also it do not show any error to me.

How to resolve this issue and where is the problem? i also asked from chatgpt but still i am stuck.

thats a reactjs code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const AssignProject = () =>
{
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    const [ data, setData ] = useState( {
        name: "",
          description: "",
          details: "",
          file:""
      } )
      // const onViewChange = ( value ) =>
      // {
      
      // }
      const change = ( e ) =>
      {
        setData( { ...data, [ e.target.name ]: e.target.value } );
    };
    
    const submit = ( e ) =>
    { 
        e.preventDefault();

        axios.post( 'http://localhost/pms/projectcreate.php', data )

        .then( ( responce ) =>
        {
         if ( responce.data = true )
         {
             
          e.target.reset();
           navigate( '/Home' );
             console.log( 'Project Added' );
             alert( 'Project Added' );
          }
          else
          {
            alert( 'Already registered Project' );
          }
        
        } );   


    }
    return (
        <>
         <div className="container">
                <div className="row mx-auto">
                    <div className="col-12 col-md-6 col-sm-4">
                        <div className="h3 mt-3">Create Project</div>

                        <form onSubmit={submit}  encType="multipart/form-data">
                        <div className="card">

                            <div className="card-body">

                                <label htmlFor="" className="form-label">Project Name</label>

            
 <input className="form-control mb-2" type="text" name="name"
 placeholder="Enter Task Name" id="" value={data.name} onChange={change}/>


                                <label htmlFor="" className="form-label">Description</label>
                                <input className="form-control mb-2" type="text" name="description" placeholder="Enter Project Description" id="" value={data.description} onChange={change}/>

                                <label htmlFor="" className="form-label">Details</label>

                                <input className="form-control mb-2" type="text" name="details" placeholder="Enter Project Details" id="" value={data.details} onChange={change}/>

                                <label htmlFor="" className="form-label">File</label> 
                               
                                <input type="file"   className="form-control mb-2" name="file" id="" value={data.file} onChange={change}/>

                                <input type="submit" value="submit" className="btn btn-primary"/>

                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
)

}
export default AssignProject
```

Thats a php code

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type");
header("Content-Type: application/json");

include('DbConnect.php');

mysqli_error($db);


$postdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
if (isset($postdata) && !empty($postdata)) {

    $request = json_decode($postdata);

    $name = $request->name;
    $description = $request->description;
    $details = $request->details;
    $file = $request->file;

    $fname = $file['name'];
    $ferror = $file['error'];
    $ftmp = $file['tmp_name'];

    $fext = explode('.', $fname);

    // If the extension is like JpG, convert it to lowercase like jpg
    $fcheck = strtolower(end($fext));

    $fextstored = array('docx', 'pdf', 'ppt');

    if (in_array($fcheck, $fextstored)) {
        
        $destinationfile = 'file/' . $fname;

        move_uploaded_file($ftmp, $destinationfile);

        $res1 = "SELECT * FROM create_project WHERE name = '$name'";
        $count = mysqli_query($db, $res1);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($count) == 0) {

            $q = "INSERT INTO `create_project` (`name`, `description`, `details`, `file`) VALUES ('$name','$description','$details','$destinationfile')";

            $query = mysqli_query($db, $q);
            if ($query)
                echo "<br>Project added!";
            else
                echo "<br>Already Added";
        }
    }
}

?>
```